# How to read messy xml data row by row in JavaScript in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a messy xml data source(which is not in my control and will not be in my control anyway).

[image: messy xml data source]

As you can see that there is ONLY ONE node which contains many lines of data.

For each line of data, there are many different fields without headers or start/close tags, so it makes parsing these lines of data into small chunks very different.

I am in Sencha Touch and using JavaScript.

The further-est step I can think is to first get the big chunk data out of the  tag and then I have no idea how to do the next.

Any advice is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Wrapping CSV data in a couple of XML tags doesn't make it XML. That data format is pretty terrible.

Comment: Hi @EvanTrimboli  I totally agree with you. However, this is not my data source thus, I can only read it but have no access to rectify its structure. Please do not down vote my question because of other's fault. thx

Comment: I didn't. But tagging this as XML is a stretch.

Comment: hi @EvanTrimboli I don't tag it as XML, the data source itself does.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `split` the data into an array based on the newline `\n`.  Then it looks like you could split on comma to get the columns.  Here is an example:

```
        var rows = myInfo.split('\n');
        console.log(rows);
        Ext.each(rows,function(row){
           var columns = row.split(',');
           console.log(columns)
        });
```

I made a [working fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/59u) for demonstration.

**Update:**

On demonstration sites like JSFiddle or Sencha Fiddle you can't typically connect to a live source for an ajax request because of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  They take dummy data and basically fake a response.

I wasn't able to get any data back from the url you posted in the fiddle. Additionally, it looks like there may be an issue with the xml parser in sencha.fiddle.  I've created a dummy example in JSFiddle of an ExtJS ajax request with the parsing information included.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ac8Fk/

The basic code would be as follows:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'/echo/xml/',//the js fiddle required url for example ajax requests
    method:'POST',
    params:{//These parameters are just passed this way for JSFiddle
        xml:'<data>dsajjdsj,34343,434343\ndfgsdf,34343,43</data>',
        delay:1
    },
    success:function(response){       
        var data = response.responseXML.documentElement.textContent;
        var rows = data.split('\n');
        Ext.each(rows,function(row){
            var columns = row.split(',');
            console.log(columns);
        });
    }
});
```

If you can provide dummy data i can modify the example to include data more similar to your data.

Comment: Thank you :), in my case there is no '\n' inside the big chunk of data. But I will give it a try and see whether it works or not.

Comment: the `\n` represents a new line. When displaying data you don't see it.  However, your end of line character could be different in your data.

Comment: Hi weeksdev, thank you for your reply. I followed your instruction but replaced your data and put in the now.xml, then nothing works. Could you please have a look? thanks https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/59u

Comment: Hi weeksdev, thank you for your update. However, the demo data is too simple to reflect my problem, so I updated your data and put a fragment of my data source, then the demo stops working. Also here is the data source if you need to have a look. (Thank you for you help :))http://webtrak.bksv.com/mel/data/46608654

Comment: Cool, thanks. I checked out your data in notepad++ (which allows visibility into the newline character) there are trailing crlf's.  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nU2K/) with data similar to yours. Hope this helps.